# How do specify the resolver (and GHC) Travis should use to test my Haskell package?

Tags: haskell, testing, config, travis-ci, software-distribution

I'm trying to test [my Haskell package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma) against several [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org) resolvers on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs), but my `--resolver` environment variable is being ignored.

For example, if I specify

```
env:
- ARGS="--resolver lts-4.0"
```

in my [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/.travis.yml),  I still still seem to be using a different resolver (the one in [my `stack.yaml`](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/stack.yaml)?) and GHC, as shown by lines like

```
Installing library in
/home/travis/build/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-9.1/8.0.2/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.2/crypto-enigma-0.0.2.9-6Cs7XSzJkwSDxsEMnLKb0X
```

in the corresponding [build log](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/jobs/266286949), which indicates a different resolver (9.1), and corresponding GHC (8.0.2) being used.

How should my build (`stack.yaml`, `.travis.yml`, etc.) be configured to ensure that the resolvers (and corresponding GHC) I specify are used to preform my Travis builds and tests?

Comment: Where do you actually use `ARGS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `env` you just define environment variables. You still have to use them. `stack` on its own does not respect the `ARGS` variable, so use it in your script, e.g.

```yaml
install:
# Build dependencies
- stack $ARGS --no-terminal --install-ghc test --only-dependencies

script:
# Build the package, its tests, and its docs and run the tests
- stack $ARGS --no-terminal --install-ghc test --haddock --no-haddock-deps
```

You should probably use a better name, for example `RESOLVER`:

```yaml
env:
- RESOLVER=lts-4.0
- RESOLVER=lts-6.0
- RESOLVER=lts-8.0

install:
# Build dependencies
- stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --only-dependencies

script:
# Build the package, its tests, and its docs and run the tests
- stack --resolver $RESOLVER --no-terminal --install-ghc test --haddock --no-haddock-deps
```

Also keep in mind that it's usually a better idea to use multiple `stack.yml` to hold the configuration for that specific LTS variant.

For more information, see [`stack`'s Travis documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/travis_ci/) and [Travis' environment variables documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/).

Comment: So each value of `RESOLVER` will be used in turn?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius yes, each environment will be used in turn.

Comment: Ah, I see: I misread "does not respect `ARGS`" to mean that Travis didn't have a clever way of using `env`.